# Asp.net datetime culture issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime, cultureinfo, culture

I have encounter an issue while working with `datetime` in asp.net. While sending datetime string from an textbox to DateTime according to the Turkish Culture, the `datetime` format is breaking.

For instance; i am sending these parameters on querystring -

?`beginDate=02.01.2014&endDate=03.01.2014`, these parameters values appear like the following when passed ActionResult parameter -

`beginDate = 01.02.2014, endDate = 03.01.2014`.

I tried a couple solution but problems still exists.

**1)**

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("tr-TR");
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("tr-TR");
```

}

**2)**

```
<globalization uiCulture="tr-TR" culture="tr-TR" />
```

**3)**

```
return Json(_db.GetList(Convert.ToDateTime(begin, new CultureInfo("tr-TR")), Convert.ToDateTime(end, new CultureInfo("tr-TR")))
```

**4)**

```
begin.Value.ToString("dd.mm.yyyy")
end.Value.ToString("dd.mm.yyyy")
```

**Url**

```
domain.com/Home/GetList?begin=02.01.2014&end=03.01.2014
```

**GetList Method**

```
public JsonResult GetList(DateTime? begin, DateTime? end)
{
    return Json(_db.GetList(Convert.ToDateTime(begin, new CultureInfo("tr-TR")), Convert.ToDateTime(end, new CultureInfo("tr-TR")))
}
```

Comment: please show the code where you are converting these querystring parameters back to datetime.

Comment: querystring parameters binding directly

Answer (score 0):

The default model binder is **culture agnostic** for GET parameters. This means that you should always use the `yyyy-MM-dd` following format when you are sending dates as query string parameters to a controller action:

```
?beginDate=2014-01-02&endDate=2014-01-03
```

The culture comes into play if you were sending those dates in the payload of a POST request.

And there's a reason behind this implementation details. You could read more about it in the following article: http://weblogs.asp.net/melvynharbour/archive/2008/11/21/mvc-modelbinder-and-localization.aspx

This being said you could get rid of all the 1., 2., 3., 4., 5. points you tried and simply use the `begin` and `end` DateTime parameters. You don't need to be setting the culture info of your application.